# Spring boot with JPA and ManyToMany: JsonIdentifyInfo not working properly

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I've two classes which are causing a problem: `Teacher` and `SchoolClass` (`class` is a Java keyword already). Both have a `long id.`

A teacher can have many classes and a class can have many teachers.

If I request a teacher I get *(only the importent vars)*:

```
{
  "classes": [
    {
     "teachers": [
       {
        "classes": [
          1
        ],
       }
     ],
    }
  ]
}
```

But if I request a class I get *(complete)*:

```
{
  "timestamp": 1445530016078,
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "exception": "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException",
  "message": "Could not write content: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Long (through reference chain:
     at.scool.model.db.SchoolClass[\"teachers\"]->java.util.HashSet[0]->at.scool.model.db.Teacher[\"classes\"]->java.util.HashSet[0]);
     nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException:
     java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Long (through reference chain:
     at.scool.model.db.SchoolClass[\"teachers\"]->java.util.HashSet[0]->at.scool.model.db.Teacher[\"classes\"]->java.util.HashSet[0])",
  "path": "/api/class/1"
}
```

**Teacher**

```
@ManyToMany
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
private Set<SchoolClass> classes = new HashSet<>();
```

**SchoolClass**

```
@ManyToMany
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
private Set<Teacher> teachers = new HashSet<>();
```

How to fix this error?

### Update

I noticed now, that the `property` value 'id' is not taken in SchoolClass. *(start of output with `JsonIgnore` on teachers set)*

```
{
"@id": 1,
"id": 1,
```

Comment: Have you tried using the `ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class` generator instead of `PropertyGenerator`?

Comment: not yet, cause my ids are `long`

Comment: It's actually not necessarly the same type as the id of your entity, it's the type used for `@id` which can be different from your id, and will be unique just for the current output, and will replace the object by this id.

Comment: it's working now: thx || is there a way to hide @id in the output?

Comment: I don't know, but that would be weird to hide it cause it's the only thing that allows you (or the user of your API) to make the connexion further in your JSON.