# REST send ManyToMany back to Server

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

I've a `@ManyToMany` with a `@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class)`.

If I send the object back I get:

```
error: "Bad Request"
exception: "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException"
message: "Could not read document: No _valueDeserializer assigned↵ at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@3021b8dc; line: 1, column: 244] (through reference chain: at.scool.model.db.Teacher["classes"]->java.util.HashSet[0]->at.scool.model.db.SchoolClass["teachers"]->java.util.HashSet[0]->at.scool.model.db.Teacher["id"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No _valueDeserializer assigned↵ at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@3021b8dc; line: 1, column: 244] (through reference chain: at.scool.model.db.Teacher["classes"]->java.util.HashSet[0]->at.scool.model.db.SchoolClass["teachers"]->java.util.HashSet[0]->at.scool.model.db.Teacher["id"])"
path: "/api/teacher/1"
status: 400
timestamp: 1446921619542
```

### source code

[Spring boot with JPA and ManyToMany: JsonIdentifyInfo not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33285941/2715720)

**Teacher**

```
@ManyToMany
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
private Set<SchoolClass> classes = new HashSet<>();
```

**SchoolClass**

```
@ManyToMany
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
private Set<Teacher> teachers = new HashSet<>();
```

Comment: are you sure you have proper syntax ??

Comment: updated post with my code

Comment: @rala did you get the solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*@zt1983811*
*well yes - I found a solution which I forgot to post here*
*one reason: I don't think this is 'well' programmed, but here we go:*

**answer**

one class need the `@JsonIdentityInfo` on top:

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class)
public class Teacher {
// ...
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JsonBackReference(value = "teachers")
private School school;
```

the other one needs it at the variable:

```
@ManyToMany
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class)
private Set<Teacher> teachers = new HashSet<>();
```