# @JsonIdentityInfo ObjectIdGenerators returning 3 instead of object

Tags: java, rest, jpa, spring-boot

A question from the past: [Spring boot with JPA and ManyToMany: JsonIdentifyInfo not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33285941/2715720)

### The Code

**Teacher**

```
@ManyToMany
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class)
private Set<SchoolClass> classes = new HashSet<>();
```

**SchoolClass**

```
@ManyToMany
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class)
private Set<Teacher> teachers = new HashSet<>();
```

The output from teacher is now:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  // reduced content
  "classes": [
    {
     @id: 1,
     id: 1,
     // reduced content
    },
    3 // <- no class object
  ]
}
```

In the database itself there is everything correct linked.
The `getClasses()` from `Teacher` method has also the correct object in the array.

Why is there just `3` instead of the object?
*btw: the correct object id would be 4*

Comment: Did you try with (generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class)?

Comment: I am not sure but instead of using annotation on the collection, can you annotate respective classes and try?

Comment: Can you put this annotation on the class itself: @JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class) public class Teacher {////} and same for the SchoolClass?

Comment: this works now; but from the school class I get 4 (OneToMany)

Comment: You mean School.class has 4 Teacher.class?

Comment: no the number instead of object ^^'

Comment: Did you remove the @JsonIdentityInfo from property and put them in the Teacher.class and SchoolClass.class?